# GitHub readme styles hide on GitHub

Tags: github, markdown, readme

I have a GitHub `readme.md` when published to GitHub pages I would like for the readme to take into consideration the `<style>...</style>` code that I have written at the bottom of the page. However I would like this to be hidden when viewing the readme on GitHub.com is anyone able to help me with this? Currently the code isn't visible on GitHub pages however on my profile/in the repo's `readme` section it displays the style tag at the bottom.

I've tried changing the flavour of markdown to kramdown which didn't work.

The linked question doesn't answer my question, I want to be able to hide the `<style>` tags from appearing in my readme on my profile.